# Microsoft Dynamics GP SUTA Report Running Slowly

Tags: performance, report, dynamics-gp

We are running Microsoft Dynamics GP version 11.00.1860 (SP2) and we're having issues running our SUTA report for this past quarter (10/01/2011 - 12/31/2011).  It's running incredibly slowly.  The quarter before that, it ran for 3 hours.  I ran a SUTA report at the beginning of the week for this past quarter and it ran for 22 hours.  I'm running it again right now and it looks like this one will finish in 50 hours (same report... just seeing if the issue had cleared up... no luck).

Here are the things I tried before my current SUTA Summary report run to clear up the issue (which, if the current estimated time is any indication, none of these worked)

1. I'm only running the SUTA Summary (no FUTA or any other report at the same time)
2. We run Greenshades Center in GP.  I've disabled it for now.
3. I cleared out the UPR10400 table of any old report records
4. I've deleted the temporary files out of my C:\Windows\Temp directory and my user's temp directory
5. I've moved the report dictionary file to a local directory from a directory on our shared network drive.

Has anyone ever run into this issue before?  If so, what did you do to fix it?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After many calls to Microsoft support, we were given the following index creation statement which ended up fixing the issue.  Our "50 hour" report is now running in an hour and change. :)

```
CREATE INDEX [Performance1_UPR30300] ON [dbo].[UPR30300] ([EMPLOYID], [PYRLRTYP], [PAYROLCD], [YEAR1], [CHEKDATE], [DEX_ROW_ID]) ON [PRIMARY]
```